# jQuery .position().left and variables

Tags: jquery, html, css, variables, position

How do I make it so the slider only slides left till the "red" slide and right till the "green" slide with the jQuery below? I feel like I am missing something simple, but I am not seeing it as of now. The moveLeft function appears to work, but moveRight does not.

```
var slideWidth = $('#mySliderContainer').width();
var slideCountWidth = $('#mySlider').children().length;

var min = 0;
var max = -(slideCountWidth -1) * slideWidth;

function moveLeft() {
  $('#mySlider').animate({
    left: '+='+slideWidth
  }, 400);
  if($('#mySlider').position().left >= min) {
    $('#mySlider').animate({left: '-='+slideWidth});
  }
};

function moveRight() {
  $('#mySlider').animate({
    left: '-='+slideWidth
  }, 400);
  if($('#mySlider').position().left <= max) {
    $('#mySlider').animate({left: '+='+slideWidth});
  }
};
```

The link to where the jQuery is being implemented is located on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwierzba/uhtxtnks/).

Ideally, if you try to go past the min and max slides, it should bounce back (either to the "red" or "green" slide). I am obviously doing something wrong with this bit of code.

```
var max = -(slideCountWidth -1) * slideWidth;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `max` is correct as the dragging is working correctly. Your problem seems to be that you are doing the bounce back script in `moveRight()` disconnected and in parallel to the normal animation. This means that when you check `position().left <= max`, the div is often halfway between slides and the comparison isn't accurate.

I would do the position check *before* you do the standard animation and then chain the bounce back to the standard one if required:

```
function moveLeft() {
    var isMin = $('#mySlider').position().left >= min;
    var a  = $('#mySlider').animate({
        left: '+='+slideWidth
    }, 400);

    if(isMin) {
        a.animate({left: '-='+slideWidth});
    }
};

function moveRight() {
    var isMax = $('#mySlider').position().left <= max + slideWidth;
    var a = $('#mySlider').animate({
        left: '-='+slideWidth
    }, 400);

    if(isMax) {
        a.animate({left: '+='+slideWidth});
    }
};
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhtxtnks/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the problem is your max value isn't accounting for the margins that the slider container is contributing to the value of the slider position left.

Change your max calculation to this:

```
var max = (-(slideCountWidth -1) * slideWidth) + parseFloat($("#mySliderContainer").css("marginLeft")) ;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uhtxtnks/9/

To clarify, you can add an alert in your moveRight() function to output the value of $('#mySlider').position().left after the animation. Note that when you get to the green slide, the value is actually -629.5 (at least on my fiddle), and not the -750 you'd expect. That's because the jQuery .position().left method is adding the left margin of the #mySliderContainer element to the offset, and that margin is 120.5 (on my fiddle). So to account for that, you'll just need to add that container left margin to the max calculation.